# VueJS not being rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying this simple snippet:

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    collapseOnScroll: true,
  }),
})
```

`App.vue`:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card class="overflow-hidden">
      <v-app-bar
        :collapse="!collapseOnScroll"
        :collapse-on-scroll="collapseOnScroll"
        absolute
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        dark
        scroll-target="#scrolling-techniques-6"
      >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

        <v-toolbar-title>Collapsing Bar</v-toolbar-title>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-checkbox
          v-model="collapseOnScroll"
          color="white"
          hide-details
        ></v-checkbox>
      </v-app-bar>
      <v-sheet
        id="scrolling-techniques-6"
        class="overflow-y-auto"
        max-height="600"
      >
        <v-container style="height: 1000px;"></v-container>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

But when I open `http://localhost:8080/` I only see a blank page. Nothing is being rendered, although there is no error on my dev tools and I don't see any error either in my console. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the render part of your Vue constructor. `render: h => h(App)`

Comment: If i add this, i'll get Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Comment: Ah okay, you may need $mount. Have a look at this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you export your root component but do not render it. To render it use this line of code `render: h => h(App)`. Also Vue need to know where to **mount** your Vue instance, so call method `$mount`, and provide CSS selector of `DOM` element, where Vue instance will be mounted.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! Just one thing: i'm getting a 'router is not defined' error, so it still doesn't render

Comment: Do you have your router object? If yes, then import it like this `import router from './router'`. If not - just remove `router` property.

Comment: Router should not give me problems, since i installed it. I tried removing it, and i'm getting the same error with 'store'. If i remove store as well, i'll get another error about the component not being mounted

Comment: Then import your store like this `import store from './store'`.

Comment: This is what i'm talking about: if i try to import them, i get a import error. Can't resolve /store

Comment: Do you have a store folder or store.js in your project? Can you provide your project's code using GitHub?

Comment: Alright, store is installed in my node_modules. The only error i get now is '[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.'

Comment: There are so many misconceptions, so please provide your code on GitHub :)

Comment: @Jack022, made everything work, give me a permission to push. **nickname**: [andrewvasilchuk](https://github.com/andrewvasilchuk).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198004/discussion-between-jack022-and-javas).